# Desktop launcher - Could not find the program

Tags: .desktop

I recently installed an application which I will use quite a lot, but it didn't come with a desktop launcher. I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 and I created the following `paraview.desktop` file in `/home/myname/.local/share/applications/`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Education;Math;Science;
Comment[en_US]=ParaView allows viewing of large data sets
Comment=ParaView allows viewing of large data sets
Exec=/opt/paraviewopenfoam56/bin/paraview
GenericName[en_US]=Data Viewer
GenericName=Data Viewer
Icon=paraview
Name[en_US]=ParaView Client 5.6.0 OF
Name=ParaView Client 5.6.0 OF
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Version=1.0
```

However, this launcher fails with the error `Could not find the program 'paraview'`.

If I run `paraview` or `/opt/paraviewopenfoam56/bin/paraview` in the terminal, they both works.

What can I try?

Comment: Application launchers usually go under `/usr/share/applications/`.... Extra information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301577/from-digikam-to-whatsapp/1319669#1319669)

Comment: @Raffa `/home/myname/.local/share/applications/` is where user-specific application launcher go.